# No puedo ingresar un vector de tipo char en una lista enlazada

Tags: c++, lista

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct nodo{
    int nro;        // en este caso es un numero entero
    string nombre;
    char cedula[9];
    string apellido;
    struct nodo *sgte;
};

typedef struct nodo *Tlista;

void insertarInicio(Tlista &lista, int valor, string dato, char _cedula[9], string _apellido)
{
    Tlista q;
    q = new(struct nodo);
    q->nro = valor;
    q->nombre = dato;
    q->cedula[9] = _cedula[9];
    q->apellido = _apellido;
    q->sgte = lista;
    lista  = q;
}

void insertarElemento(Tlista &lista, int valor, int pos, string dato, char _cedula[9], string _apellido)
{
    Tlista q;
    q = new(struct nodo);
    q->nro = valor;

    if(pos==1)
    {
        q->sgte = lista;
        lista = q;
    }

    q = new(struct nodo);
    q->nombre = dato;

    if(pos==2)
    {
        q->sgte = lista;
        lista = q;
    }

    q = new(struct nodo);
    q->cedula[9] = _cedula[9];

    if(pos==3)
    {
        q->sgte = lista;
        lista = q;
    }

    q = new(struct nodo);
    q->apellido = _apellido;

    if(pos==4)
    {
        q->sgte = lista;
        lista = q;
    }
}

void reportarLista(Tlista lista)
{   

    while(lista != NULL)
    {
        cout <<' '<< "Numero: " << lista->nro << endl;
        cout <<' '<< "Nombre: " << lista->nombre << endl;
        cout <<' '<< "Cedula: " << lista->cedula << endl;
        cout <<' '<< "Apellido: " << lista->apellido << endl;
        lista = lista->sgte;
    }

}

void menu1()
{
    cout<<" 1. INSERTAR AL INICIO               "<<endl;
    cout<<" 2. REPORTAR LISTA                   "<<endl;
    cout<<" 3. LIMPIAR PANTALLA                   "<<endl;
    cout<<"\n INGRESE OPCION: ";
}


/*                        Funcion Principal
---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

int main()
{
    Tlista lista = NULL;
    int op;     // opcion del menu
    int _dato;  // elemenento a ingresar
    string _nom;  // elemenento a ingresar
    char _cedula2[9];
    string apellido;

    do
    {
        menu1();  
        cin>> op;

        switch(op)
        {
        case 1:

            cout<< "\n NUMERO A INSERTAR: "; cin>> _dato;
            cout<< "\n NOMBRE A INSERTAR: "; cin>> _nom;
            cout<< "\n CEDULA A INSERTAR: "; cin>> _cedula2;
            cout<< "\n APELLIDO A INSERTAR: "; cin>> apellido;
            insertarInicio(lista, _dato, _nom, _cedula2, apellido);
            break;

        case 2:

            cout << "\n\n MOSTRANDO LISTA\n\n";
            reportarLista(lista);
            break;

        case 3:
            system("cls");
            break;

        }

    }while(op!=8);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mira no creo entender muy bien tu pregunta pero esto

```
 void insertarInicio(Tlista &lista, int valor, string dato, char _cedula[9], string 
_apellido)
{
Tlista q;
q = new(struct nodo);
q->nro = valor;
q->nombre = dato;
q->cedula[9] = _cedula[9];
q->apellido = _apellido;
q->sgte = lista;
lista  = q;
}
```

deberia ser asi si qieres q cedula tome el arreglo cedula...recuerda que al pasar un arreglo lo q estas pasando en realidad es la referncia al primer elemento y q cualqier cambio que hagas en cualqiera de los dos se modifica el otro

```
void insertarInicio(Tlista &lista, int valor, string dato, char _cedula[9], string 
_apellido)
{
Tlista q;
q = new(struct nodo);
q->nro = valor;
q->nombre = dato;
q->cedula = _cedula;
q->apellido = _apellido;
q->sgte = lista;
lista  = q;
}
```

ahora cedula apuntara a _cedula...Si esto resulve tu problema por favor dejamelo saber...De otra forma disuclpame por entender mal la pregunta, me explicas xq estoy mal y edito la pregunta.Salu2 ;)

Comment: He hecho la modificación que mencionas pero me sale un error de incompatibilidad sobre la asignación de char a char[9]

Comment: @Max especificame bien que hace cada cosa....para poderte ayudar mejor...y ahora q me fijo xq no simplemente declaras cedula string y ya...asi te evitas el arreglo char y es mejor...disuclpa dar una respuesta sin probarla pero es q ando con el movil

Comment: Es que en el enunciado del problema que tengo se especifica que se deben de usar vectores de tipo char para los datos personales, pero creo que tendré que pasar los string a vectores de tipo char ya que no me queda de otra. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: haber dejame ver si entiendo algo cuando te dicen vectores de tipo char se refieren a esto vector <char> bla;

Comment: asi q si es asi es incluso mas facil...pues los vectores tienen un constructor de copia asi que puedes hacer esto bla = bla1 suponiendo que ambos con vectores de tipo char...

Comment: La verdad llevo rato intentándolo y no me sale

Comment: el q no te sale se mas especifico x favor

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando intento utilizar el vector char en mi código no me sale nada al copilar o me sale un dato basura

Answer (score 0):

El problema está que en C/C++ no se puede copiar un vector con el operador "=", o sea tu problema está en la línea:

```
q->cedula[9] = _cedula[9];
```

Resolverías éste problema de la siguiente manera:

```
strcpy(q->cedula, _cedula);
```

Pero la variable **cedula** debería ser con un tamaño de diez caracteres, 9 de cédula y uno para el caracter nulo (el caracter nulo sirve para que no imprima caracteres basura).

Comment: de hecho si se puede copiar el contenido de un Vector a otro con el operador = esta sobrecargado

Answer (score 0):

Para futuras preguntas, por favor, explica correctamente el problema. No somos adivinos así que si planteas el problema de tal forma que sea sencillo de entender tu pregunta recibirá más respuestas y soluciones.

Esto es importante ya que, como verás a continuación, tu programa es una fábrica de errores tanto de código como conceptuales y en casos así es posible que quien te responda se olvide del problema que justamente te impide a tí trabajar.

Así que ya sabes, si quieres respuestas de calidad cúrrate una pregunta de calidad.

En C++ los arrays de tamaño fijo (`char array[10]`) no se pueden copiar con el operador de asignación porque no disponen de una sobrecarga válida.

Dado que ya estás usando `std::string` en tu programa te sugiero sustituir el tipo de `cedula` para que sea también un `std::string`:

```
struct nodo{
    int nro;
    string nombre;
    string cedula; // <<---
    string apellido;
    struct nodo *sgte;
};

void insertarInicio(Tlista &lista, int valor, string dato, string _cedula, string _apellido)
//                                                         ~~~~~~
{
    Tlista q;
    q = new(struct nodo);
    q->nro = valor;
    q->nombre = dato;
    q->cedula = _cedula; // <<---
    q->apellido = _apellido;
    q->sgte = lista;
    lista  = q;
}
```

Pero aquí no acaba la cosa. C++ **no es C**. C++ es un lenguaje orientado a objetos, luego no es necesario usar `struct` por todos lados:

```
struct nodo{
    int nro;
    string nombre;
    string cedula;
    string apellido;
    struct nodo *sgte;
//  ~~~~~~ Esto sobra
};

typedef struct nodo *Tlista; // <<--- Y esto también

void insertarInicio(nodo *& lista, ...) // No hace falta usar struct
```

Además el operador `new` se puede usar de forma más intuitiva:

```
nodo* q = new nodo;
```

Y, para terminar, fíjate que tu programa no es capaz de salir del bucle usando la opción 3:

```
    case 3:
        system("cls");
        break;
```

Ese `break` sirve para salir del `switch`, pero necesitarías un segundo `break` para salir del bucle `do-while`. Como no puedes anidar los bucles:

```
    case 3:
        system("cls");
        break;
        break; // Este break no se ejecutaría nunca
```

La opción es configurar correctamente la condición del bucle `do-while`:

```
do
{
  // ..
} while(op!=3); // 3, no 8!!!!
```

Y, por cierto, aunque aun no la usas, la función `insertarElemento` no va a funcionar como esperas... esta función es capaza de insertar hasta 4 elementos de una sola tacada (cuenta el número de veces que aparece `new` en esa función).